# Does Linq/.NET3.5 support a 'zip' method?

Tags: .net, linq, list-manipulation

In other languages (ruby, python, ...) I can use `zip(list1, list2)` which works like this:

If `list1 is {1,2,3,4}` and `list2 is {a,b,c}`

then `zip(list1, list2)` would return: `{(1,a), (2,b), (3,c), (d,null)}`

Is such a method available in .NET's Linq extensions?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

.NET 4 gives us a [`Zip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx) method but it is not available in .NET 3.5.  If you are curious, [Eric Lippert provides an implementation of `Zip`](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/07/zip-me-up.aspx) that you may find useful.

Comment: answered with an implementation below that does

Comment: @Steven: No, it doesn't: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,2b8d0f02389aab71

Answer (score 0):

neither implementation will fill in the missing values (or check that the lengths are the same) as the question asked.

here is an implementation that can:

```
    public static IEnumerable<TResult> Zip<TFirst, TSecond, TResult> (this IEnumerable<TFirst> first,  IEnumerable<TSecond> second,  Func<TFirst, TSecond, TResult> selector, bool checkLengths = true, bool fillMissing = false) {
        if (first == null)    { throw new ArgumentNullException("first");}
        if (second == null)   { throw new ArgumentNullException("second");}
        if (selector == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("selector");}

        using (IEnumerator<TFirst> e1 = first.GetEnumerator()) {
            using (IEnumerator<TSecond> e2 = second.GetEnumerator()) {
                while (true) {
                    bool more1 = e1.MoveNext();
                    bool more2 = e2.MoveNext();

                    if( ! more1 || ! more2) { //one finished
                        if(checkLengths && ! fillMissing && (more1 || more2)) { //checking length && not filling in missing values && ones not finished
                            throw new Exception("Enumerables have different lengths (" + (more1 ? "first" : "second") +" is longer)");
                        }

                        //fill in missing values with default(Tx) if asked too
                        if (fillMissing) {
                            if ( more1 ) {
                                while ( e1.MoveNext() ) {
                                    yield return selector(e1.Current, default(TSecond));        
                                }
                            } else {
                                while ( e2.MoveNext() ) {
                                    yield return selector(default(TFirst), e2.Current);        
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        yield break;
                    }

                    yield return selector(e1.Current, e2.Current);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: +1 for noticing the 'missing values' behaviour. However, this is an error on my part - it looks like [Python's `zip` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) *also* stops when reaching the end of its *shortest* argument, just like the Linq version. (And my assumption - shown in the question - was wrong)

Comment: It is odd for a zip function, hence it defaults to not. But I have had  a few situations were it was desirable.