# C# : How to compare two collections (System.Collection.Generic.List<T>) using Linq/Lambda?

Tags: c#, linq, generics, collections, lambda

I'm having two collections of `String` like

```
 List<String> l_lstOne = new List<String> { "100", "1X0", "X11", "XXX" }, 
    l_lstTwo = new List<String> { "000", "110", "100", "000" };
```

I need to compare the two lists and make the second list like

```
    { "000", "1X0", "X00", "XXX" }
```

**Note:**
Both the list will contain same numbe of elements and the length of each element will be same.

The comparision is like

1. If an mth element in `l_lstOne` have an 'X' in nth position, the the nth position of the mth  in l_lstTwo should be replaced by 'X'.

**Example**

```
    l_lstOne            l_lstTwo        Output

      100                 000             000
      1X0                 110             1X0
      X11                 100             X00
```

So, to solve this i used nested for loop , here is my source code,

```
 for (int l_nIndex = 0; l_nIndex < l_lstTwo.Count; l_nIndex++)
        {
            String l_strX = String.Empty;

            for (int l_nInnerIndex = 0; l_nInnerIndex < l_lstTwo[l_nInnerIndex].Length; l_nInnerIndex++)
            {
                l_strX += l_lstOne[l_nIndex][l_nInnerIndex] == 'X' ? 'X' : l_lstTwo[l_nIndex][l_nInnerIndex];
            }
            l_lstTwo[l_nIndex] = l_strX;
        }
```

This code is working fine, but the thing is, its taking more time to execute, i.e almost 600 milliseconds to process 200000 elements and each of length 16.

And moreover i need a Linq or Lambda method to resolve this. So please help me to do this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Robert Harvey : Thank you... but i don't understand what you meant by `Sort`.

Answer (score 5):

LINQ will not help you here; LINQ is not meant to modify collections.

You can make your code substantially faster by building a `char[]` instead of a `string`; right now, you're building 3.2 million `string` objects because of the `+=`.

Instead, you can write

```
char[] l_strX = new char[l_lstTwo[l_nInnerIndex].Length];

for (int l_nInnerIndex = 0; l_nInnerIndex < l_lstTwo[l_nInnerIndex].Length; l_nInnerIndex++)
{
    l_strX[l_nInnerIndex] = l_lstOne[l_nIndex][l_nInnerIndex] == 'X' ? 'X' : l_lstTwo[l_nIndex][l_nInnerIndex];
}
l_lstTwo[l_nIndex] = new string(l_strX);
```

Comment: Thank you... it reduced the processing time from 600 milliseconds to 300 milliseconds.

Answer (score 2):

Mh, if I understand it correctly the words in `l_lstOne` act as a mask for the words in `l_lstTwo` where the mask is transparent unless it's an `X`. How about this:

```
l_lstOne.Zip(l_lstTwo, 
    (w1, w2) => new String(w1.Zip(w2, (c1, c2) => c1 == 'X' ? c1 : c2).ToArray())))
```

`Zip` is a [Linq extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx) available from .NET 4 on which combines the elements of two lists like a zip. The outer zip basically creates the word pairs to iterate over and the second one creates a the mask (take all characters from the second word unless word one has an `X` in that position).

Also note that this creates a new sequence of strings rather than replacing the ones in `l_lstTwo` - that's the Linq way of doing things.

Comment: Thank you . I am using .Net Framework 3.5. So is there any alternate for `Zip`

Comment: @PramodhTS: You can find an implementation as provided by a link in an answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811822/does-linq-net3-5-support-a-zip-method

Answer (score 2):

You could do it with the following statement in .NET 3.5

```
    IEnumerable <String> result =
        Enumerable.Range(0, l_lstOne.Count)
            .Select(i => Enumerable.Range(0, l_lstOne[i].Length)
                .Aggregate(string.Empty, (innerResult, x) => innerResult += l_lstOne[i][x] == 'X' ? 'X' : l_lstTwo[i][x]));
```

Comment: Would be interesting to measure if using a `StringBuilder` instead of string concatenation in the aggregate would make a performance difference (avoids the creation of lots of temporary strings)

Comment: @ChrisWue: It would make a significant difference.  See the comment below my answer.